# .net core AsyncLocal loses its value

Tags: c#, async-await

I use a similar pattern as [HttpContextAccessor](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Http/Http/src/HttpContextAccessor.cs)

The simplified version is as follows, `Console.WriteLine(SimpleStringHolder.StringValue)` is not supposed to be null.

```
public class SimpleStringHolder
{
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<ValueHolder> CurrentHolder = new AsyncLocal<ValueHolder>();

    public static string StringValue
    {
        get => CurrentHolder.Value?.StringValue;

        set
        {
            var holder = CurrentHolder.Value;
            if (holder != null)
            {
                holder.StringValue = null;
            }

            if (value != null)
            {
                CurrentHolder.Value = new ValueHolder() { StringValue = value };
            }
        }
    }

    private class ValueHolder
    {
        public string StringValue;
    }
}
```

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<string> currentValue = new AsyncLocal<string>();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(async () => await OutterAsync());
        task.Wait();
    }

    public static async Task OutterAsync()
    {
        SimpleStringHolder.StringValue = "1";
        await InnerAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(SimpleStringHolder.StringValue); //##### the value is gone ######
    }

    public static async Task InnerAsync()
    {
        var lastValue = SimpleStringHolder.StringValue;
        await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false);
        SimpleStringHolder.StringValue = lastValue; // comment this line will make it work
        Console.WriteLine(SimpleStringHolder.StringValue); //the value is still here
    }
}
```

In the above code, `OutterAsync` invokes an async method `InnerAsync`, in `InnerAsync` the `StringValue`
is set, which makes AsyncLocal loses its context in `OutterAsync`
`Console.WriteLine(SimpleStringHolder.StringValue);` is null.

I think the magic is in the SimpleStringHolder's property set, removing the following code will make things right.

```
if (holder != null)
{
    holder.StringValue = null;
}
```

The above code works as expected.

Please help me understand what sorcery is this?

Comment: @mjwills: I couched my answer below in more mechanical terms. Like I said, the parameter-passing metaphor is good (I find it very useful conceptually), but since it's not really a parameter, I can see how it might not be the best path to understanding for everyone.

Comment: Also possibly useful: [a post I wrote about the semantics of "async local" (before that type existed)](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`AsyncLocal<T>` exists to provide a mechanism to preserve values within an asynchronous execution context. Key to this are two factors involved in your example:

1. An `await` allows a method to return to the caller, which could change the context. With the older `ThreadLocal<T>` type, when execution returns control to the method, it could be in a different thread, even though from the `async` point of view the context is the same. Using `AsyncLocal<T>` ensures that the state of the context is restored when the `await` returns control to the method after the awaitable object has completed.
2. Until something happens that would require the context to change, the current state of an `AsyncLocal<T>` object is whatever it was previously. I.e. a method essentially inherits the state the object was in when it was called. If you're dealing with simple values, no surprises lurk, but in the case of a reference type like your `ValueHolder` type, the only thing that `AsyncLocal<T>` is keeping track of is the *reference* to that object. There is still only one copy of the object, and changes to the state of any given such object work as they always do with or without asynchronous contexts floating around (i.e. they are seen by any reference to that object).

So, in the code example you've provided:

1. `OutterAsync()` sets the `StringValue` property to `"1"`, which results in a new `ValueHolder` object being created, and the `StringValue` property of that object being set to `"1"`.
2. `OutterAsync()` calls `InnerAsync()`. That method then retrieves the *`string`* reference from the holder (indirectly…i.e. by going through the `SimpleStringHolder.StringValue` property). Since no changes to the value nor the context have been made at this point, the same `ValueHolder` object is used in this case, so you get `"1"` back.
3. `InnerAsync()` awaits an asynchronous task, which causes a new execution context to be created for the purposes of isolating changes made to the `AsyncValue<T>` object to that context. **From this point on, changes to the object are *not* seen by code in a different context.** For example, the code executing in the `OutterAsync()` method.
4. After the async task completes in `InnerAsync()`, that method then sets a new value to the `SimpleStringHolder.StringValue` property. Because the earlier context was inherited, when the setter sets `holder.StringValue` to `null`, it is setting the property of the object that was created in `OutterAsync()`. **But…** because the code is in a new context, when the setter then assigns a new value to the `CurrentHolder.Value` property, that change is isolated to that context.
5. When the `InnerAsync()` method finally completes, this completes the task that the `OutterAsync()` method's `await` was waiting on. This causes the `AsyncValue<T>` to restore its state to the `OutterAsync()` method's context, which is different from the context that was in `InnerAsync()` when it updated the `SimpleStringHolder.StringValue` value. And specifically, this restored state is a reference to the `ValueHolder` object that was originally set in the `SimpleStringHolder` when the `holder.StringValue` property got set to null.
6. So, when `OutterAsync()` then goes to look at the property value, it finds it set to null. Because it was set to null.

In your own experimenting, you can either remove the null assignment altogether, or simply omit the assignment to `SimpleStringHolder.StringValue` after the `InnerAsync()`'s `await` statement (because if you don't make the assignment, then the null assignment is never executed). Either way, the null assignment doesn't happen, and so the previously-assigned value remains.

But if you do make the null assignment, the caller `OutterAsync()` is going to have its context restored, and have the holder object reference then restored, and that holder object's own `string` reference had already been set to `null`, so that's what `OutterAsync()` sees.

Related reading:
[What's the effect of AsyncLocal in non async/await code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42959056/whats-the-effect-of-asynclocalt-in-non-async-await-code)
[Why does AsyncLocal return different results when code is refactored slightly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49232514/why-does-asynclocalt-return-different-results-when-code-is-refactored-slightly)
[Does `AsyncLocal` also do the things that `ThreadLocal` does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63073439/does-asynclocal-also-do-the-things-that-threadlocal-does)